# magento changing Shipping Method

Tags: magento

in my magento project i want to change the shipping methods like

```
    * Ground $9.29
    * 3 Day Select $17.49
    * 2nd Day Air $23.17
    * Next Day Air $52.48
```

now it shows  like
Flat Rate
 Fixed $5.00

how it will do ?

Does any one help me ??

Answer (score 0):

Which shipping service do you want to use? All shipping is configured in the Admin panel under `System > Configuration > Sales > Shipping Methods`. There you can configure your system to automatically retrieve the shipping options with proper pricing as you specified. Also, turn off Flat Rate Shipping if you don't want the $5.00 option to appear anymore.